# View animations with Snapkit

Tags: swift, snapkit

I tried different tutorials for making light animations with Snapkit but nothing seems to help. I even tried Spring framework, but that didn't work as well. Here is my code.

```
private func setupMatchView() {
    view.addSubview(matchOverlayView)
    matchOverlayView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.topMargin)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.bottomMargin)
        make.left.equalToSuperview()
        make.right.equalToSuperview()
    }
    matchOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    view.addSubview(matchView)
    matchView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(32)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(32)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    }
    matchView.backgroundColor = .white
    matchView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    matchView.dropShadow()

    matchView.addSubview(matchYourImageView)
    matchYourImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.width.equalTo(100)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(40)
    }
    matchYourImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.77, blue:0.77, alpha:1.00)
    matchYourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    matchYourImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    matchView.addSubview(matchHerImageView)
    matchHerImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.width.equalTo(100)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview().inset(-20)
        make.top.equalTo(matchYourImageView.snp.top)
    }
    matchHerImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.69, blue:0.69, alpha:1.00)
    matchHerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    matchHerImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    matchView.addSubview(matchLabel)
    matchLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(matchYourImageView.snp.bottom).offset(64)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    }
    matchLabel.text = "Match"
    matchLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .heavy)

    matchView.addSubview(matchCTA)
    matchCTA.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(matchLabel.snp.bottom).offset(40)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(32)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(32)
        make.height.equalTo(44)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(40)
    }
    matchCTA.setTitle("Go To Chat", for: .normal)


    matchView.addSubview(matchCloseButton)
    matchCloseButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(32)
        make.height.equalTo(32)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
    }
    matchCloseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Close"), for: .normal)
    matchCloseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonTapped(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

    matchView.layoutIfNeeded()

    hideMatch()
}

@objc func closeButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    hideMatch()
}

private func hideMatch() {
    self.matchOverlayView.alpha = 0
    self.matchView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().offset(self.view.frame.height)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.matchView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
private func showMatch() {
    self.matchOverlayView.alpha = 1
    self.matchView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().offset(0)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.matchView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

And that doesn't work. When user triggers `showMatch()` method, that view just shows, there is no animation. If anyone can help that would be swell.

Answer (score 8):

You have to call `layoutIfNeeded` on `matchView`'s superview:

```
private func showMatch() {
    self.matchOverlayView.alpha = 1
    self.matchView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().offset(0)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

When you call `layoutIfNeeded` on a `UIView` the layout engine uses that view as root view and starts to layout all of that view's subviews. But only the subviews!

That's why the layout change is not animated when you call `layoutIfNeeded` on `matchView`. You have to call `layoutIfNeeded` on one of `matchView`'s superviews to trigger the layout change.

Answer (score 4):

The only existing answer didn't work for me.
Here's what worked for me.

```
let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.2, curve: UIView.AnimationCurve.linear, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.matchView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().offset(0)
    }
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})

anim.startAnimation()
```